# Variational calculus on Lie algebra valued one forms - Chern-simons theory

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, principal-bundles, quantum-field-theory, variational-analysis

The action in the Chern-Simons theory is given as:

$$S=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{Tr}(A  \: \wedge \:dA + \frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A).  $$
The [wikepida page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory) gives the euler lagrange equations as $0=\frac k{2\pi}F=
\frac k{2\pi}dA+A\wedge A$.

Here is my attempt
$$ \delta S=\frac{k}{4\pi}\delta\int_M \text{Tr}(A  \: \wedge \:dA + \frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A) $$
Assuming $\delta$ commutes with taking the integral and taking the trace
$$ =\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \delta\text{Tr}(A  \: \wedge \:dA + \frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A) $$
$$ =\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{Tr}(\delta(A  \: \wedge \:dA + \frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A)) $$
$$ =\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{Tr}(\delta(A  \: \wedge \:dA + \frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A)) $$

$$ =\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{Tr}(\delta(A  \: \wedge \:dA)) + \text{Tr}(\delta(\frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A)) $$
$\delta$ has a Leibniz rule
$$\text{Tr}(\delta(A  \: \wedge \:dA))=\text{Tr}(\delta A  \: \wedge \:dA+ A  \: \wedge \:\delta dA)$$

$$\text{Tr}(\delta(\frac{2}{3}A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A))=\text{Tr}(\frac{2}{3}(\delta A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: A+A \: \wedge \:\delta A \: \wedge \: A+A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: \delta A))=\text{Tr}(\frac{2}{3}(A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: \delta A))$$

Putting this back together:
$$ \delta S=\frac{k}{4\pi}\delta\int_M \text{Tr}(\delta A  \: \wedge \:dA+ A  \: \wedge \:\delta dA) +\text{Tr}(\frac{2}{3}(A \: \wedge \:A \: \wedge \: \delta A)).$$

I do not see how to continue this further. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925872/deriving-classical-equations-of-motion-for-chern-simons-theory) attempts this question another way. I do understand how they conclude from $ 0=\frac{k}{4 \pi} \int_M \text{Tr} \bigg[a \: \wedge \: (2dA \: + 2A \: \wedge \: A) \bigg]$ that $\frac{k}{2 \pi}F=0.$

Comment: In the last display, I don't think the $\delta$ in front of the integral should be there.

Comment: In the second term of the integral, you can commute $\delta d = d\delta$. You then need to integrate that term by parts. After that you should rearrange the order of the wedge products so the $\delta A$ is the first factor in all 3 terms. Then, since $\delta S = 0$ for all variations $\delta A$, the second factor inside the integral is identically zero, which gives you the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: So $\text{Tr}(\delta A  \: \wedge \:dA+ A  \: \wedge \:\delta dA)=\text{Tr}(\delta A  \: \wedge \:dA+ A  \: \wedge \:d\delta A)= \text{Tr}(\delta A  \: \wedge \:dA)+ \text{Tr}(A  \: \wedge \:d\delta A)$. Then we want to integrate the second term by parts $\int \text{Tr}(A  \: \wedge \:d\delta A)=\text{Tr}(A\wedge \delta A)-\int \text{Tr}(dA\wedge A)$? This does not seem to give to correct answer?

Comment: You didn’t integrate by parts correctly. You have to use Stokes’ Theorem.